# ActiveRecord/Postgres: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to retrieve contacts, which have many activities, where the max completed_date of the latter was 6 months ago. Let me ilustrate it:

```
user = User.first
user.contacts.first.activities.maximum(:completed_date)
# SELECT MAX("activities"."completed_date") AS max_id FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 12]]
=> 2014-03-18 09:06:54 UTC
```

Thats perfect. Now I want to use that a clause for a WHERE query but it seems I can't:

```
user.contacts.joins(:activities)
  .where('MAX("activities"."completed_date") < ?', Time.now - 6.months)
# SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"
# INNER JOIN "activities" ON "activities"."contact_id" = "contacts"."id"
# WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 AND (MAX("activities"."completed_date") <= '2013-09-23 05:55:21.191254')  [["user_id", 12]]

#=> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
#   LINE 1: ...ntacts"."id" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 AND (MAX("activ...
```

How I'm supposed to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is complaining because of the `MAX`, aggregate function, call in the `WHERE` clause.

To avoid this problem call `MAX` in `SELECT` with `AS` to alias it.  Then use the alias in the `WHERE`.

```
user.contacts.select('*, MAX("activities"."completed_date") AS max_complete_date').joins(:activities)
     .where('max_complete_date < ?', Time.now - 6.months)
```

**Edit**

I appologize, you should use `HAVING` instead.

```
 user.contacts.joins(:activities)
   .having('MAX("activities"."completed_date") < ?', Time.now - 6.months).group("contacts.id")
```

Comment: That seems just right, but it complains about `max_completed_date` column not existing (`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "max_completed_date" does not exist`).

Comment: And using having also rises `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "contacts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Does adding `.select("DISTINCT ON (contacts.id) *")` solve it for the edit?

Comment: Sry for the delay, no it keeps raising the same error.

Comment: Add `.group("contacts.id")` to the end of the edited `having` solution above.